# linker error using static linking in g++

Tags: g++

I am using other people's makefile and get troubles when trying to compile a 'static' version of the exe

I have printed out the makefile's rules and the error is like this:

```
g++ Main.or System.or Options.or -Wall -lz --static -o main
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If I do not include the '--static' option in the above command, it works fine.

The makefile also have rules to generate the static lib:

```
ar -rcsv lib_release.a  Main.or System.or Options.or
r - Main.or
r - System.or
r - Options.or
Making Soft Link: lib_release.a -> lib.a
ln -sf lib_release.a lib.a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-static` linkage option instructs the linker to ignore all shared
libaries (`libname.so`) that could resolve the `-lname` linkage options (both explicit
and default) and accept only static libraries (`libname.a`). You have shared libraries installed on
your system that satisfy `-lz`, `-lstdc++`, `-lm` and `-lc` but no static ones.

For your linkage to work as it stands you must install the static libraries:

- `libz.a`  (Compression library)
- `libstdc++.a` (The standard C++ library)
- `libm.a`  (The math library)
- `libc.a`  The standard C library

by the method that is appropriate to your distro.